# How to extract currency and number attributes from a sample price in java

Tags: java, format, locale, currency, price

I am retrieving different values for my product price in different currencies
Eg:

```
$ 1213.22
1213\.22 $
R$ 1213,22
```

I want to store these values in a formatted Java object such that I can extract:

1. The currency symbol
2. The separator between whole price and fractional price
3. The whole price
4. The fractional price

Is there a utility to do this apart from using regex?

**Solutions explored**

1. I cant find a way to reverse engineer the below solution so that I can get NumberFormat to accept my retrieved values

   ```
   java.util.Currency usd = java.util.Currency.getInstance("USD");
   java.text.NumberFormat format = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
   format.setCurrency(usd);
   ```
2. Same problem as no.1

   ```
   StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
   Formatter f=new Formatter(builder);
   f.format(Locale.FRANCE,"%.5f", -1325.789);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a class like this and have methods to return the value you want.

   ```
    public class Price {
    private String currency;
    private String separator;
    private int wholePrice;
    private int fractionalPrice;

    public Price(String currency, String separator, int wholePrice, int fractionalPrice) {
        this.currency = currency;
        this.separator = separator;
        this.wholePrice = wholePrice;
        this.fractionalPrice = fractionalPrice;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public String getSeparator() {
        return separator;
    }

    public int getWholePrice() {
        return wholePrice;
    }

    public int getFractionalPrice() {
        return fractionalPrice;
    }
    }
   ```

Or if immutable, use a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
record Price ( String currency, String separator, int wholePrice, int fractionalPrice ) {}
```

2. And then have this code to update your class and this way you will be able to access any attribute as required.

   ```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\p{Sc})\\s*(\\d+)([,.])(\\d+)$");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(priceStr);

   if (matcher.find()) {
       String currency = matcher.group(1);
       String separator = matcher.group(3);
       int wholePrice = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
       int fractionalPrice = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4));
       Price price = new Price(currency, separator, wholePrice, fractionalPrice);
       System.out.println("Currency: " + price.getCurrency());
       System.out.println("Separator: " + price.getSeparator());
       System.out.println("Whole price: " + price.getWholePrice());
       System.out.println("Fractional price: " + price.getFractionalPrice());
   } else {
       System.out.println("Invalid price format");
   }
   ```

Hope This helps

Comment: The given regular expression assumes the currency symbol is at the start, the fraction is at the end and does not consider the comma separator for thousand . Can you help me update the regex for sample values like:
1,213.22 $
R$ 1213,22

Comment: I was able to update it for the below 2 sample data like:
```^([A-Z]*\p{Sc})\s*(\d+)(,*)(\d+)([,.])(\d\d)$```

$ 1,213.22
R$ 1213,22

But the one where currency symbol can be at the end is still pending..

Comment: `^(\p{Sc}|\p{Sc}\s)?(\d{1,3}(?:[., ]\d{3})*)([,.])(\d{2})\s?(\p{Sc})?$` I believe this should fit your case.